# Pinterest rich pin not working for html website

Tags: html, pinterest

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj4Mw.png)

anyone know? what's the problem 
here are the tags i m using in html.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Deft Multi-concept Coming Soon Template" />
<meta property="og:description" content=" build you online presense righ now with a beautiful coming soon tempalte." />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.coderare.com/deft-coming-soon-template.html"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Coderare" />
<meta property="og:price:amount" content="12.00" />
<meta property="og:price:currency" content="USD" />
<meta property="og:availability" content="instock" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.coderare.com/img/5.png" />
```

and when ever i'm tring to validate my page it shows "Something went wrong on our end" what's that?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [pinterest documentation](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/rich-pins/products/) the product tags you have used are not the ones pinterest supports. Instead use `product:price:amount` `product:price:currency`

You might also want to include structured data from http://schema.org for information not included in the pinterest product tags, eg In Stock.

Stackoverflow's help section has further information on debugging steps that will help you narrow down problems to the exact lines that cause the errors.